# Python3 Function with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a function to iterate over the list. Can anyone let me know and explain that what t is that I am doing wrong?

```
iplist = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']

def ip_addr(addr_list):
    for ip_addresses in addr_list:
        return ip_addresses


test = ip_addr(iplist)

print(test)
```

I am expecting output:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
```

However, I am getting the following output:

```
1.1.1.1
```

Thanks,

Comment: A `return` ends the function, and therefore breaks the for-loop

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Replace the `return ip_address` with `print(ip_address)`? All your function does is loop over the list anyway

Comment: `print` is not going to allow `test` to be set as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you return at the first iteration of the loop, then you get only the first iteration.
Try that:

```
iplist = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']

def ip_addr(addr_list):
    addresses = ""
    for ip_addresses in addr_list:
        addresses += ip_addresses + "\n"
    return addresses  

test = ip_addr(iplist)
print(test)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns the value it encounters in the first iteration of the for loop, causing the loop to terminate immediately.  Instead of a loop, join the values of the list together and return them all in one string.

```
def ip_addr(addr_list):
    return "\n".join(addr_list)
```

Comment: This is more pythonic

Comment: This is also a valid solution!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you are trying to do, but here are some solutions:

```
iplist = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']

def ip_addr(addr_list):
    for ip_addresses in addr_list:
        yield ip_addresses


test = ip_addr(iplist)

print(*[ip for ip in test])
```

or just

```
iplist = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']
print('\n'.join(iplist))
```

Comment: Yield is cool, but doesn't help here. The list goes in as a list and yield returns the list. Nothing has changed

Comment: @MichaelG. I do not know, what he/she is trying to do. Maybe there is more behind it, like some string manipulation?

Answer (score -1):

Above to all valid answers, you can also use a dummy empty list and append inside the values and return that dummy list too.